# unable to flash micropython to esp 32: open serial error

Tags: python, esp32

issue: unable to flash micropython to esp 32: open serial error, please try again. hope to connect internet and try again.

pretty new to micropython - want to flash micropython to esp 32 ( resp 8266) board.

cf this docs: https://maker.pro/esp8266/tutorial/using-micropython-on-an-esp8266-with-upycraft

getting this errors all the time.

```
open serial error, please try again.
hope to connect internet and try again.
current version only open py txt json ini file.
hope to connect internet and try again.
hope to connect internet and try again.
```

i run Win 7

the hardware:

a. **Joy-IT-Node MCU ESP8266**

.. and besides that i also tried it with the following

b. **ESP32-T Development Board CP2102 with Espressif ESP-WROOM-32 IoT** WLAN & BLE Modul

**yes:** i have installed the > CP210x_Universal_Windows_Driver.zip

by the way: i could try to do all that on a linux machine. - on a MX-Linux-Sytem

any idea;

many thanks for any and all help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As of my opinion, You don't necessarily depend on the uPyCraft IDE. So there are several other ways to develop scripts and uploading them to Your board.

Some days ago I was facing problems with Python on the NodeMcu as well. Since I didn't like the tutorials around the web, I've set up one on GitHub, covering the end-to-end process (required software, drivers, firmware images, developing, flashing, uploading, etc.): [python2nodemcu](https://github.com/pixelstuermer/python2nodemcu).

It depends on Mac and the NodeMcu board, but some of the topics may apply to other operating systems and boards as well.

And I think it covers the most relevant parts of the whole process, using the easiest tools around the web. Please have a look at it, but all in all it goes like this (short version of the linked documentation above):

- Install [Python 3](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-374)

  - Verify with `python --version`
  - Or `python3 --version`
- Install the correct SiLabs driver to enable serial USB-to-UART communication

  - See [here](https://www.silabs.com/products/development-tools/software/usb-to-uart-bridge-vcp-drivers)
- Find the device file (representing the interface to the physical device)

  - Try it using `ls -la /dev/tty.*`
- Download the recent MicroPython firmware

  - You need the [right one for Your board](http://micropython.org/download)
- Install the two Python-based libraries [EspTool](https://github.com/espressif/esptool) and [PySerial](https://github.com/pyserial/pyserial)
- Try to erase the flash of Your device

  - Run `python3 esptool.py --port /dev/tty.{device-file} erase_flash`
- Try to flash the [original](https://nodemcu-build.com) image or the MicroPython firmware to the board

  - Run `python3 esptool.py --port /dev/tty.{device-file} write_flash 0x00000 {micropython-image-or-original-firmware}.bin`
- Try to connect to the board via the REPL prompt

  - Run `screen /dev/tty.{device-file} 115200`
  - You maybe need to try different baud rates (depending on Your driver, cable, etc.)
- Connect to the board using [Ampy](https://github.com/scientifichackers/ampy)

  - For example, try to list the files on Your device executing `python3 ampy/cli.py --port /dev/tty.{device-file} --baud 115200 ls`
  - Again, try other baud rates

Anyway, I've noticed that You do not necessarily need to push the physical flash button on the device.